# How to get Min() and Max() in Excel depending on another column?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function, excel-2010

i have a excel table with some players info, team and year, from this i want to know the min year a player started in team and max year that he played for team.

Example:-

```
col 1 (names) Col2(Team)  Col3 (year)   Col 4(team)       Col5(min year)    Col6(max year)
Santosh        XXX         2000           XXX                1999              2001
Santosh        XXX         2001           XXX                1999              2001
Santosh        XXX         1999           XXX                1999              2001 
pavan          YYY         2005           YYY                2005              2007
pavan          YYY         2006           YYY                2005              2007
pavan          YYY         2007           YYY                2005              2007
Santosh        YYY         2005           YYY                2005              2005
```

Output in Col 4, Col5 Col6 is needed. Pls help

---

Here's the whole table again, **with tabspace** characters instead of spaces, **for copy-pasting** directly to Excel: You have to go to the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8033944/edit) page of this post - there in the Markdown source code box you can copy the table with correct tabspace characters. (In the Markdown-rendered form, the Cell-separating tabspace characters are replaced by space characters.)

<sub><sub>`col 1 (names)    Col2(Team)    Col3 (year)    Col 4(team)    Col5(min year)    Col6(max year)
Santosh    XXX    2000    =B2    =MIN($C$2:$C$8*($A2:$B2=$A$2:$B$8))    =MAX($C$2:$C$8*($A2:$B2=$A$2:$B$8))
Santosh    XXX    2001    =B3    =MIN($C$2:$C$8*($A3:$B3=$A$2:$B$8))    =MAX($C$2:$C$8*($A3:$B3=$A$2:$B$8))
Santosh    XXX    1999    =B4    =MIN($C$2:$C$8*($A4:$B4=$A$2:$B$8))    =MAX($C$2:$C$8*($A4:$B4=$A$2:$B$8))
pavan    YYY    2005    =B5    =MIN($C$2:$C$8*($A5:$B5=$A$2:$B$8))    =MAX($C$2:$C$8*($A5:$B5=$A$2:$B$8))
pavan    YYY    2006    =B6    =MIN($C$2:$C$8*($A6:$B6=$A$2:$B$8))    =MAX($C$2:$C$8*($A6:$B6=$A$2:$B$8))
pavan    YYY    2007    =B7    =MIN($C$2:$C$8*($A7:$B7=$A$2:$B$8))    =MAX($C$2:$C$8*($A7:$B7=$A$2:$B$8))
Santosh    YYY    2005    =B8    =MIN($C$2:$C$8*($A8:$B8=$A$2:$B$8))    =MAX($C$2:$C$8*($A8:$B8=$A$2:$B$8))`</sub></sub>

Comment: And what do you expect Col 4, Col 5 and Col 6 to show if a player has played for more than one team?

Comment: col 1 2 3 i have 4 5 6 i want as output

Comment: You don't understand. If Santosh also played for YYY in 1998 what are you going to display then?

Comment: You should either drop COl 4 and just list min and max year for team in Col 2 or add another column to list which team he played for in his min year and which team he played for in his max year.

Comment: @ flesk i changed layout in question pls have a look. YYY will be displayed and min max will be 1998 and 1998 only in col 5 6

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of very complicated ways to do this using multiple formulas, but this is exactly what a pivot table is for.

1) Select the data in columns 1 to 3

2) Insert Pivot table (Easiest to have this on a new worksheet)

3) Put a checkbox next to player and team in the fields list - what this is saying is that you want to know about each player, but also each team they played for. So you won't just see that Santosh finished in 2005 you'll see he took a break after 2001 and came back for a year.

4) To Get your minimum and maximums you now want to drag the year in to the Sum Values box (Sum looks like a Greek E) and you want to do this twice. Now you will have two columns both of which seem like random numbers.

5) Click the down arrow next to Sum of Year in the Sum Values box and choose Value Field Settings. Choose Min from the list

6) Click the down arrow next to Sum of Year2 in the Sum Values box and choose Value Field Settings. Choose Max from the list

You should now have this data set:

```
Row Labels  Min of Year Max of Year
pavan       2005        2007
    YYY     2005        2007
Santosh     1999        2005
    XXX     1999        2001
    YYY     2005        2005
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a starting point. **Unfortunately it doesn't work correctly yet. So someone would have to debug it.** The idea is using **[Array Formulas](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx)** (Using Arrays Of Data). **You must enter them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.** Then `{` `}` will appear around your Formula. You only have to do that for the first row (`E2:F2`) - then you can just copy those down.

Assuming `col 1 (names)` is in cell `A1`.
This is the Formula for `E2`: `{` `=MIN($C$2:$C$8*($A2:$B2=$A$2:$B$8))` `}` (Note that you cannot enter the `{` `}` curly braces, that's just how Excel marks Array Formulas.)

Here's the whole table, just for copy-pasting purposes: You have to go to the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9636487/edit) edit page of this post - there in the Markdown source code box you can copy the table with correct tabspace characters. (In the Markdown-rendered form, the Cell-separating tabspace characters are replaced by space characters (and don't align properly).)

<sub><sub>`col 1 (names)   Col2(Team)  Col3 (year) Col 4(team) Col5(min year)  Col6(max year)
Santosh XXX 2000    =B2 =MIN($C$2:$C$8*($A2:$B2=$A$2:$B$8)) =MAX($C$2:$C$8*($A2:$B2=$A$2:$B$8))
Santosh XXX 2001    =B3 =MIN($C$2:$C$8*($A3:$B3=$A$2:$B$8)) =MAX($C$2:$C$8*($A3:$B3=$A$2:$B$8))
Santosh XXX 1999    =B4 =MIN($C$2:$C$8*($A4:$B4=$A$2:$B$8)) =MAX($C$2:$C$8*($A4:$B4=$A$2:$B$8))
pavan   YYY 2005    =B5 =MIN($C$2:$C$8*($A5:$B5=$A$2:$B$8)) =MAX($C$2:$C$8*($A5:$B5=$A$2:$B$8))
pavan   YYY 2006    =B6 =MIN($C$2:$C$8*($A6:$B6=$A$2:$B$8)) =MAX($C$2:$C$8*($A6:$B6=$A$2:$B$8))
pavan   YYY 2007    =B7 =MIN($C$2:$C$8*($A7:$B7=$A$2:$B$8)) =MAX($C$2:$C$8*($A7:$B7=$A$2:$B$8))
Santosh YYY 2005    =B8 =MIN($C$2:$C$8*($A8:$B8=$A$2:$B$8)) =MAX($C$2:$C$8*($A8:$B8=$A$2:$B$8))`</sub></sub>